# Discord bot python, no output to command no errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote a "whois' command on discord.py and The code does not show output or any errors! and this has been happening with multiple commands. so here is the code

**Code:**

```py
 @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def whois(self, ctx, *,member : discord.Member):  #i think the error is here.
        '''
        User Info for basic info on that said User!
        '''

        with open('storage//pp.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        member = discord.Member

        mes = [
            "me",
            "Me",
            "ME"
        ]

        if member == mes:
            member = ctx.author

        prefix = prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)]

        roles = [role for role in member.roles]


        embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.set_author(name=f'User Info - {member}')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name='ID:', value=member.id)
        embed.add_field(name='Guild name:', value=member.display_name)
        embed.add_field(name='Created At:', value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p "))
        embed.add_field(name='Joined At:', value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p "))
        embed.add_field(name=f'Roles ({len(roles)})', value=" ".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
        embed.add_field(name='Top role:', value=member.top_role.mention)
        embed.add_field(name="Platform", value=f"{'Mobile' if member.is_on_mobile() else 'PC'}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Admin?", value=f"{member.guild_permissions.administrator}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Bot?', value=f"{'Bot' if member.bot else 'Human'}", inline=True)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I don't know what is the issue and it does not send any output on the terminal nor discord. so I am really lost

Comment: it should be ```color``` not ```colour``` in ```embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, t...``` and also, how can ```member == mes:```? you can do like ```member in mes:```

Comment: I'll try it.. in a bit

Comment: Discord.py is no longer maintained, I don't think It'll be a great question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @daysling but I'm using discord.py rewrite?

Comment: @GhostOps and no that's not it. its not working. i really don't know what's going on this used to work.

Comment: With what I have understood, if you use slash commands, you should be fine. Or just hope for someone to fork the discord.py repo.

Comment: @ChaoticNebula I'm confused sorry? so Is it a prefix thing?

Comment: Rapptz has a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1). It has everything (probably)

Comment: @ChaoticNebula So what I got is that it's like a whole new bot thing that isn't supported on python.  does that mean that i should just drop developing my bot on python..?

Comment: @batbeat what is the instance ```commands``` in your code? (Client, Bot, or whats the instance you've used?)

Comment: Im a verified bot developer, and of course, no one wants their bot to die. Discord.py will work till April 2022. Till then you have time to switch to slash. Also don't let the hopes down, someone might fork it and continue to maintain it.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time I'm new to this scene, question. how do you convert? into slash commands.

Comment: @batbeat seems like you are using a normal text command, and whats the ```self``` mean? Is it inside a class?

Comment: @batbeat try [this](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) to convert your commands to slash commands, and also, whats the error you are getting from you code?

Comment: @GhostOps So I've been trying to look that up do I just change the prefix or like? im confused to what's going on.

Comment: @batbeat look up on YouTube for discord.py slash commands tutorials. they should help you out!

Comment: @batbeat discord slash is easy to setup, no prefix are required, but first whats the error you are getting? try reading discord.py api docs and there'll be a function/method like ```on_command_error```, make something so that it prints the error to your discord channel, and tell whats the error..

Comment: @ChaoticNebula So converting all my commands to slash commands is the way to go? and should I stop using the rapptz api :( , i looked it up i have to install the slash thing via pip

Comment: @batbeat yes, we doesn't mean that you have to, but we recommend something which is easier than what you are doing rn

Comment: @GhostOps I already have an (on error) cog. maybe it's that. But i might really renovate my bot . I didn't know that rapptz api is going outdated.

Comment: @GhostOps So I should just use discord's api instead and the new slash command python package?

Comment: @batbeat yep, there's nothing to do with api call or requests, the discord_slash package will do all you want... try it

Comment: So, Again im so sorry for wasting your time im a noob can you add me on discord real quick? MonkeSteak#0069

Comment: `pass_context` was removed in the discord.py rewrite (v1.0) and is no longer necessary ([source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#context-changes)). I don't know whether using it here causes a problem though.